# Corona SDK: add velocity to non physics objects

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk, game-physics

I wanted to set a linear velocity to an object without having to add it as a physics body. How do I do that? Is is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that, but what you can do is set the optional property isSensor  as true in order to avoid visual collition.

For example:

```
physics.addBody(myOject, "dinamyc", { density = 0, friction = 0, bounce = 0 ,isSensor = true})
```

You can find more info here :

http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies#body.isSensor
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/isSensor.html

Comment: I had done that, but I thought it wouldn't detect collision, but it actually just doesn't "bounce" and the collision functions are still called. I read the links you posted and was able to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None that i know off, your best bet would be to recode a simili physics engine or to add features to the existing engine. Both options would be troublesome :)